# Simple GET-POST reply

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

Can't figure this out, should be an easy one for someone. Just getting a 500 server error reply and expecting it to show 'success'.

```
import webapp2
page = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="success" name="radius" >
    <input type="submit">
</form>
  </body>
</html>
"""
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(page)
    def post(self):
        radius = self.request.get("radius")
        self.response.out.write(radius)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

app.yaml is as follows

```
application: udatest85
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
```

Comment: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: Do you mean 500? Not 200? 200 is a successful response.

Comment: You may need to add a header with the Content-Type or output valid HTML

Comment: Thanks Matt, but that didn't help me unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to believe, but the problem is that I was using a mixture of tabs and spaces with my indentation. I removed the spaced indentation and replaced with tabs, problem solved.

Also, I was using notepad++ to write the code. Have since moved to PyCharm.

Thanks for your help, it's going to solve a lot of headaches for me from now on.

Comment: No worries, have to wait another 11 hours.

Answer (score 1):

When I run that exact code with this app.yaml it seems to work. A button appears upon pressing you get the success message.

```
application: stackquestion
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

Can you post your app.yaml?

Comment: More info on webapp2 and app.yaml here: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/quickstart.html

Comment: application: udatest85
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"

Comment: ok, well, as it works fine with mine and you are not uploading anything why not just replace your app.yaml with my example one and then add things as you need them? When it breaks, you know what broke it then.  It might also help if you edit your question and add in your app.yaml in code format.

Comment: in any case, I've got it to work fine with your app.yaml now anyway. up to date SDK? Right version of python etc?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. App Engine SDK is up to date, my Windows version of GAE Launcher is up to date, I've tried using your app.yaml example and I've also tried to publish the app to see but no luck. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Hmm. Got a different pc you can get set up on, just as a test? Code etc seems fine so not solvable at that level i think.

Comment: Try downloading an ide such as pycharm, free 30 day trial. Use their make new gae project option, comes with a hello world test. If that works then its a start. I dont use the launcher so perhaps something subtle there I cant help with. And pycharm will call the devserver for you so if the problem is with the launcher then at least thats bypassed. Unlikely but...

Comment: Thank you for your help Paul. I used pycharm and showed an error of 'mixture of tabs and spaces'. Just removed any indentation and replaced with tabs and the problem is solved.

Comment: Great! FYI The google style guide recommends using spaces only. http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Indentation#Indentation